# utilizando price para setar o valor do input checkbox a ser calculado

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Eu tenho alguns checkbox que possuem um valor x, que ao estarem selecionados realizam a soma do valor dos mesmos.

Porém este valor esta sendo pego através do Value, e eu precisava utilizar de um atributo que substituisse o value para que eu possa enviar como input checked ao banco.

atualmente está assim...

```js
var itens = document.querySelectorAll("tr td option");
var resultado = document.getElementById("result");
for ( i = 0,  soma = 0; i < itens.length ; i++){
    itens[i].onchange = function(){
     if (this.checked==true) {
      soma = soma + parseInt(this.value);
     }
        else {
            soma = soma - parseInt(this.value);
        }
        resultado.setAttribute("value","R$ "+soma+",00")
    }  
}

String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;

    if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }

    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

    return v;
};
String.prototype.toFloat = function() {
    var v = this;

    if (!v) return 0;
    return parseFloat(v.replace(/[\D]+/g, '' ).replace(/([\d]+)(\d{2})$/, "$1.$2"));
};
(function(){
    "use strict";

    var $chs = document.querySelectorAll('input[calc="ch[]"'),
        $result = document.getElementById('result'),
        chsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call($chs);

    chsArray.forEach(function(element, index, array){
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){
            var v = this.value,
                result = 0;
            v = v.toFloat();

            if (this.checked === true) {
                result = $result.value.toFloat() + parseFloat(v);
            } else {
                result = $result.value.toFloat() - parseFloat(v);
            }

            $result.value = "R$ " + String(result).formatMoney();
        });
    });

}());
```

```html
<label>A ideia é o value ter o valor de 1 para enviar ao banco e adicionar um atributo tipo preco="100,00" que irá levar o valor a ser calculado</label>

<br>

<input id="cmn-toggle-7" name="NomeDoCampo" calc="ch[]" value="100,00" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox">

<input id="cmn-toggle-8" name="NomeDoCampo2" calc="ch[]" value="100,00" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-center-yes-no" type="checkbox">

<input type="text" name="TotalCalculado" id="result" class="input-xlarge" value="R$ 0,00">
```

"a ideia é o value ter o valor de 1 para enviar ao banco e adicionar um atributo tipo preco="100,00" que irá levar o valor a ser calculado"

o que eu poderia ajustar no code para que funcione corretamente, to a um tempinho trancado nesse detalhe hehe vlw gnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```
<input id="cmn-toggle-9" type="checkbox" data-price="100,00"....
```

e o acessar via javascript:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('cmn-toggle-9');
var price    = checkbox.dataset.price;
```